# Praying Namaz (Salah) & Durood e Ibrahimi

Tags: salat, practical-islam

As-Asalamu Alaykum,

I wanted to clarify when praying Farz Namaz (Fard Salat) when to recite durood e Ibrahim. I am asking since I want to clarify someone’s conept.

Example: (for this example I am using Magrib)
When I pray Magrib. I pray 3 rakat farz and 2 rakat sunna. 
I recite Durood e Ibrahimi in 3rd rakat ( after attahiyat ) of magbrib and 2nd rakat of sunna.

When praying Farz and Sunnah in Magrib Is it Allowed to skip Durood e ibrahimi in the 3rd rakat of farz Namaz and only recite durood in sunnah?